# Increasing class pointer array

Tags: c++

In my code, I want to add one student info into my class pointer array and the array size will increase each time a new student is added. Here is my code:
My header file:

```
class Student{
public:
    int studentID;
    char studentName[20];
    int currentEnrollment;
    Student();
void AddStudent(Student *tempStudent[], int countStudent, int sizeOfArray);}
```

My Class definition file:

```
    void Student::AddStudent(Student *tempStudent[], int countStudent, int sizeOfArray)
{
    for (int i = countStudent; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter student id (4 digits only): ";
            cin >> tempStudent[i]->studentID;
            cout << "Please enter student name: ";
            cin >> tempStudent[i]->studentName;
        }
}
```

My Main.cpp file

```
int *totalStudent = new int;
*totalStudent = 1;
int i, j, countStudent = 0;
int sizeOfArray = *totalStudent;
Student *newStudent[*totalStudent];
//Each time a new student is added, I will allocate a new memory for the array element, then add student Info using function.
    for (i = countStudent; i < *totalStudent; i++)
        {   
            newStudent[i] = new Student;
            newStudent[i]->AddStudent(newStudent, countStudent, sizeOfArray);
            countStudent++;
            *totalStudent++;
        }
```

When I run my code, I get an undefined reference error, so I do not know If I am able to increase my array or not. I intend to use C++ syntax so I use new and delete. Thank you for your help. 
P.S: Here is my new code and it runs great, the only missing is the studentID for the first element in array.
In my main class:

```
int numStudent = 0;
int i, j, countStudent = 1;
Student *newStudent = new Student[countStudent];
AddStudent(newStudent, countStudent, numStudent);
```

My Student.h

```
    class Student{
    public:
        int studentID;
        char studentName[20];
        int currentEnrollment;

};
Student AddStudent(Student *newStudent, int &countStudent, int &numStudent);
```

and My Student.cpp

```
    Student AddStudent(Student *newStudent, int &countStudent, int &numStudent)
{
        Student tempStudent;
        cout << "Please enter student id (4 digits only): ";
        cin >> tempStudent.studentID;
        cout << "Please enter student name: ";
        cin >> tempStudent.studentName;
        newStudent[numStudent] = tempStudent;
        numStudent++;
        if (numStudent == countStudent)
        {
            Student *newStudentSize = new Student[countStudent + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < numStudent; i++)
            {
                newStudentSize[i] = newStudent[i];
            }
            delete []newStudent;
            return *newStudentSize;
            countStudent += 1;
        }
}
```

Running this code will give me the following result:

```
StudentID: 11
StudentName: Dat
StudentID: 23
StudentName: Michael
Printing:
StudentID: 0
StudentName: Dat
StudentID: 23
StudentName: Michael
```

Comment: Why all the pointers? What's wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: VLAs (`Student *newStudent[*totalStudent];`) are not valid C++. Also, you can't just access memory that hasn't been allocated which is being done in the loop

Comment: First, I do not learn about vector yet. Second, it is not allowed in this assignment, so I have to stick to pointer, struct, and class and something less complex.

Comment: Your code is kind of messy, so it is hard to see what you are trying to do. And trying to fix your code without untangeling that mess will just be a long game of "whack a mole". A few tips: `int *foo = new int;` typically is a sign of lack of basic understanding. Take a breath and flip a few pages back in your tutorial. Next: When you have method `bar` and write `foo.bar(....)` it is expected that `bar` acts on the object `foo`. Your method `AddStudent` does not. Tip: If you had  class `Student` and `University`, what kind of object should `AddStudent` modify?

Comment: Would you please explain to me what is the problem with my addStudent method? I know that there must be some logical error in it, but I still cant see what the problem is. I would think that the class object that I input to the method will actually add value to itself because the tempStudent is a pointer class so it is pass-by-reference.

Comment: I do not know why you added method "addStudent" in class student. I think you need a new class to manange student object.

Comment: Note that `Student();` only declares a constructor. Unless you defined it somewhere else you need `Student(){}`. This is probably what's causing the undefined reference error you're seeing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it doesn't make sense to increase the array for each new student (it's inefficient) here's one way you can do it (I didn't even try to make your code compile because it has a number of issues and is unnecessarily complicated). Note that  `tempStudent` (in the code snippet below) doesn't even have to be created using `new`. This solution stores `Student` objects in the students array (although it's easy to modify it to store `Student` object pointers instead). That said, usually, you'll just want to create an array of large enough size to accomodate all students (just set `studentCount` to some appropriate number and not 1 like in the example below).

```
class Student{
public:
int studentID;
char studentName[20];
int currentEnrollment;
Student(){};
};

   int main(){
   int studentCount=1;
   Student * students = new Student[studentCount];

    int numStudents=0;    
    bool done=false;    
    char finished='N';

    while (!done){

          //Student *tempStudent = new Student();
          //create a Student on the stack
          Student tempStudent;

          cout << "Please enter student id (4 digits only): ";
          //No input checking is done here
          cin >> tempStudent.studentID;
          No input checking is done here
          cout << "Please enter student name: ";

          cin >> tempStudent.studentName;

          students[numStudents] = tempStudent;

          numStudents++;

          cout << "Stop entering students:  Y or N";

          cin >> finished;

          done = finished=='Y' or finished=='y' ? true : false;


          if(numStudents==studentCount){

              students = ReallocateStudents(students, studentCount, studentCount*2);

              studentCount *= 2;

                    }
    }//end while

  //print the students info
    for(int i=0;i<numStudents;i++){
            Student st = students[i];
            cout << st.studentID << "     "  << st.studentName << std::endl;

    }
    //deallocate the students array or if you place this in the main like you did, the program will exit immediately so there's no need to deallocate
    return 0;
    }

Student * ReallocateStudents(Student* st, int oldSize, int newSize){

                Student * newStudents = new Student[newSize];

                //copy the existing values from the old array to the new one

                for(int i=0;i<oldSize;i++){

                    newStudents[i] = st[i];
                }
                delete [] st; //delete the old array

                return newStudents;  
}
```

UPDATE:

Since you don't want to do everthing in the `main()`, just create a free `AddStudents` function and do everything there. Alternatively, you can create a
 static function inside the Student class. It makes no sense to create `AddStudent` as a member of `Student` because that would require you to use an instance of  Student to add a new instance, which makes for poor design (not to mention technical issues etc).

```
int main(){

// some code here
 Students * allStudents = AddStudents();

//print students
}//end main

 Students * AddStudents(){

   int studentCount=1;

   Student * students = new Student[studentCount];

    int numStudents=0;    
    bool done=false;    
    char finished='N';

    while (!done){

          //create a Student on the stack
          Student tempStudent;

          cout << "Please enter student id (4 digits only): ";
          //No input checking is done here
          cin >> tempStudent.studentID;
          No input checking is done here
          cout << "Please enter student name: ";

          cin >> tempStudent.studentName;

          students[numStudents] = tempStudent;

          numStudents++;

          cout << "Stop entering students:  Y or N";

          cin >> finished;

          done = finished=='Y' or finished=='y' ? true : false;


          if(numStudents==studentCount){

              students = ReallocateStudents(students, studentCount, 
              studentCount*2);

              studentCount *= 2;

                    }
    }//end while

   return students;
}
```

This is simple and easy to both understand and maintain so I suggest using this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am now able to modify my code with your instruction and my code runs ok right now. The only problem that I have in my code right now is the first studentId that I add is showing a "0" value no matter what number I put in. Please look at my code again.

Comment: @Dat To, Make sure that you start at index 0. You haven't posted your modified code so I can't be certain as to what's wrong.

Comment: I have updated my code, Please help me take a look. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You still haven't posted the part that calls `AddStudent`. Also, using reallocation like you did (inside `AddStudent`) doesn't affect the original pointer (passed argument Student* newStudent). You would have  pass by reference for this but there's really no need for this. Do you need to call `AddStudent` in a loop or can you just  do everthing (populate all students) inside it , much like I did.

Comment: I did add the call function in my main. I do not need to call AddStudent in a loop anymore if I have a function like this my Student class. Plus I have to write each function and header separately so in my main, I only have to call the function to do everything because I have about 13 function for this so it is not possible to inlcude everything in main. What is the good way to using reallocation, do I need to write a separete function and use that function in the if statement to increase my array size?. Thank you\

Comment: If I use a separate function to increase my array size like you did above, such as: newStudent = IncreasingSize(newStudent, countStudent, countStudent + 1); Then I will get an error that said "cannot convert "Student" to "Student*" in assignment which I understand that my object Student cannot passed as a pointer to a function parameter?

Comment: Dear, Thank you for your help. I have solved my problem using your approach before, but I take out the delete oldarray part as it causes a memory problem since the oldarray is not allocated any memory using new. Plus I have a hard time trying to understand this part in your code: students = ReallocStudent(); I understand that you will assign our new bigger array's size to old array student. But If i use the samething in my code, it will give me an error saying student cannot be convert to "Student*" . So I have to modified it to student[numStudent] and it works just fine. Please explain to me.

Comment: I know assign student[numStudent] is wrong in someway as it only applies the 'element' of that array to equal a new array, not a whole array. Plus in my main class, I declare a pointer of Student class like you did in your code. Then when I print my array, I only need to use '.' access operator instead of pointer operator '->' . If I use the '->' to access class pointer member, it will give me an error saying class pointer expected to use '->'. Do you know why it happen?

Comment: @Dat To, where exactly (which line) do you get that error?

Comment: In your code, it should be the last part, delete[] st

Comment: @Dat To, inside `ReallocateStudents()` ?

Comment: it is after that part, Your code is delete []st; then return newStudent;

Comment: @Dat To,  You're doing something differently but I can't tell exactly what since you haven't posted the part that calls `AddStudent`.  If it's still `newStudent[i]->AddStudent(newStudent, countStudent, sizeOfArray);`, then you will have to redesign your solution. Note that newStudent pointer can't be changed inside `AddStudent` because it's passed by value (that is only the copy is passed). Also, make sure that you don't try to delete an already deleted pointer ( use if(ptr) delete [] ptr;

Answer (score 0):

`addStudent` does not do anything with the `Student` object it belongs to. So there is no need to put it in the 'Student' class. (Or you could rather rewrite it so it does something with the student object it belongs to). And it currently does not "add" anything, so the name is confusing.

What is technically wrong with it depends on what you want it to do. Currently it initializes student objects expected to already exist and pointed to by an array, from a specific array index, to the end of the array. That could well be a useful function, if that is what you want it to do. But you then must call it correctly with an array of pointers that point to valid `Student` objects, which you currently do not.

Currently in main you have a loop that initializes pointers in an array. And each time you initialize a pointer, you call AddStudent(..). The problem is that 'AddStudent()' tries to initialize ALL the student pointed to by your array.

This has two major problems (In addition to all the other problems with your loop).

1. Each time you create a new student, all your existing students will be
     initialized again with new input from std::cin. (So for n students, you will
     try to do n*n initializations)
2. While the loop in `main` is running, not all pointers in your array points 
     to existing `Student` objects. This may result in important data being 
     overwritten, a program crash or something totally different and unexpected.

You should sit back and reevaluate how you want to do things. Trying to fix single bugs in your existing code, one after another, will just create more bugs.

Just a hint to get you started:

```
class Student
{
public:
    int studentID;
    char studentName[20];
    int currentEnrollment;
    Student();
    void init_from_cin();
};
```

And in your class definition file:

```
void Student::init_from_cin()
{
   cout << "Please enter student id (4 digits only): ";
   cin >> studentID;
   cout << "Please enter student name: ";
   cin >> studentName;
}
```

If you create a new `Student` like this:

```
Student *new_student = new Student;
new_student->init_from_cin();
```

Then after calling `init_from_cin()`, the `Student` object pointed to by `new_student` should be initialized.

How to create and initialize multiple `Student` objects in a loop, is left as exercise for the reader. But when you do it, you should understand what your lower and upper bounds of your loop are supposed to be. And you should also understand why moving the upper bound further away while your loop is running is a bad idea.

And never forget that sane programming languages start array indexing with 0.